# Better ways to check if textFields are empty and contain valid values in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin7

I need to do some validation on my vaadin application. I have several textFields to check, and the first thing I need to do is to check if they are empty or not. I know there is an isEmpty method but as I have a few to check is there a better way to check them all together at the same time? Like, would it be a good idea to get the textFields in an array or List and loop through them? 
Also one more thing about validation. Some of these textFields are supposed to contain integers, well, I should say, the values are supposed to be parsed as integers. A quick look in the vaadin API doesn't show any suitable method so I will check whether those strings are parsable as ints

Answer (score 0):

To your first part of the question: If your fields are in a form, set the fields to required. During form.commit() the emptyness is tested automatically.

To the part with the integer-fields: You can use this on your textfields:

```
setConverter(new StringToIntegerConverter());
```